# When updating a jar I now get a class not found error

Tags: java, ant

In my project I had this dependency:

> dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-bundle" rev="2.7.16"

I updated it to:

> dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-bundle" rev="3.0.0-milestone2"

After doing that and recompiling I now get a Error:

> Could not find or load main class

If I go back to the previous revision all is well again.

How can I find out what the issue is in the updated bundle that would be causing me to get this error?  I'm assuming here that it's either a different jar that I need that was removed from the newer bundle or there is an updated jar that is affecting this but I am at a loss to figure out which.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you run the app ?

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: The app is run for testing from the command line like so: 
java -cp pm_gpcs.jar  com.pm.gpcs.GpcsProcessing GetSchedules  '{"site":["ACME7"]}'

I'm using IVY to manage the jars and as mentioned when I change from cxf-bundle version 2.7.16 to 3.0.0-milestion2 I then get the can't find class error.

I'm not sure what I can provide as a minimal reproducible example without providing all the code, which I can not do.   However I will see if I can reproduce this with different code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found out what was going on.  I was trying to also remove unused jars and that would cause the issue.
I got side tracked because the error was telling me it couldn't fine my class.  If it had given a different class name then it would have been easier to figure out.